# Nojde.js insert Self = this in every files

Tags: node.js

I need to access the `self` of all files of my application.

if I insert the code `self = this;` in files(modules) I can access `this` outside of the module. Why do I need it?

After I `require` a module, I inject some functions in the modules, eg:

```
 var mymodule = require('mymodule')

 mymodule.somevar = 'somevalue';
 mymodule.doSomethingWithSomevar = function (obj) {
    console.log(self.somevar );
};
```

If I insert `self = this;` inside the `mymodule` file the command `console.log(self.somevar );` works and I can access the value of `self.somevar`, but I dont want to insert that line in every file, is there any way to make it automatic?

Comment: Why do you need self? in this situation "this" whould work.

Comment: You're right, actually in my real project I was using `myinstance.apply(null, method)` to execute the function, and I changed to `myinstance.apply(myinstance, method)` and now it worked! thank you!